# How do i define the position for the background image in css?

Tags: css

Setting the background image is clear, but how do i set the position for the background-image?

Answer (score 1):

The [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp) property, e.g.

```
background-position:top right;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a background image with no-repeat positioned 10px to the right and 20px from the top

```
{ backgroud: url(path to image) no-repeat 10px 20px; }
```

you can use negative values for the position too, eg. -10px to move it 10px to the left

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use shorthand to set everything at the same time!

`background:#ffffff url('/images/background.jpg') top right no-repeat;`